# EmguCV issue with Android Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, android, opencv, xamarin, xamarin.android

i would like to some assistance in a code that i am doing on Xamarin studio with emgu CV wrapper. i am developing an android app using opencv(emgucv) with C#.

1. In my code header area it gives error of namespace of emgucv (namespace using Emgu.CV;)
2. it work fine if i change it to - using Emgu.CV; .
3. After this i get some assembly error when i try to build the project, screenshot of the error list is attached on this link-> https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOhqv.jpg
4. Another screen shot of the error is on this link -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkPxl.jpg
5. the error text is "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
   File name: 'System.Drawing.dll'
   at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() (assad)"

   6. I have tried the project by removing the Visual Studio dll files for emgucv but it gives the same error

Comment: You need to remove those references to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.*` in your project as those are not available under `Xamarin.Android`.

Comment: You need to post the errors as **text**, not as screenshots. Thanks.

Comment: @SushiHangover is there any issue with emgucv version ?